# C Primer Plus 6th ed chapter 6 programming exercise 4

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

With the following code I was able to change the first letter of every row and have all the letters printed but not as required.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
//This is a program to print a pattern of the letters
//A to U.  Printing a number of letters
//with the row number. First row/one letter, second row/
//two letters, etc.
//A
//BC
//DEF
//GHIJ
//KLMNO
//PQRSTU

#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 6
#define CHARS 21

int main(void)
{
    int row;
    char ch;

    for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(ch = ('A' + row); ch < ('A' + CHARS); ch++)
            printf("%c", ch);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const size_t N = strlen(s);

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ");

        size_t n;
        if (scanf("%zu", &n) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        size_t k = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                printf("%c", s[ k++ % N ]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like:

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 12
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
VWXYZAB
CDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRS
TUVWXYZABC
DEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZ
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Comment: You call yourself beginner? As I was scrolling down, I thought the answerer were 50 rep user :)

Comment: @machine_1 There is a logical mistake in your reasoning. An experienced programmer can have the reputation about 50 points because he does not answer questions. And a beginner can have a relatively high reputation because he answers questions helping other beginners.:)